# Mutual Funds and SIP

Tags: stocks, mutual-funds

Say if I am investing in a Mutual Fund with a planning to continue the SIP for 20 years with 3000 per month and increment it by 10% each year, but after 5 years the Mutual Fund starts to suffer heavy loss and I withdraw my money seeing this situation. Now If I start investing in a new mutual with Rs.5,314.68 monthly (since my 3000 with 10% increment per year will now be this amount) and increment it also by 10% per year for next 15 years will I get the same profit as if i continued to invest in the same mutual fund for 20 years? My profit will be decrease right? since I am starting all new? What to do in these scenarios? Can I invest the money that I have obtained after 5 years from that initial mutual fund to my new mutual fund and then start SIP on that? Is this even possible?